# ansible include_vars undefind issue while using loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have playbook, where i'm trying to loop through the `include_vars` but somehow `loop` is not working

Below is my playbook and Error.

Any hint or help with be much appreciated.

### Playbook:

```
---
- name: Running AWS EC2 Play ...
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ secret_aws.yml }}"
        - "{{ aws_vars.yml }}"
      no_log: true
```

### Error

```
TASK [include_vars] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/aws/aws_work/new_create_awsVM.yml:8
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "'secret_aws' is undefined"
}
```

### Note

It works while assigning `include_vars` separately.

```
- include_vars: aws_vars.yml
- include_vars: aws_secerets.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use interpollation like varts but your file names are not a vars. juste remove interpolation:

```
---
- name: Running AWS EC2 Play ...
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - secret_aws.yml
        - aws_vars.yml
```

Comment: I tried but it only allows after a certain interval.